# How to apply function to elements of a list without creating a new list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to apply a function to all elements in the list, but I want to actually change the elements (which are objects), not view results. I think this is the problem with using `map()` or list comprehensions.

```
class Thing(object):
    pass

# some collection of things
my_things

# they are all big...

# produces SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[i.size = "big" for i in my_things]

# produces SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment
map(lambda i: i.size="big", [i for i in my_things]) 

# no error, but is it the preferred way?
for i in my_things:
    i.size="big"
```

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

And what's wrong with

```
for i in my_things:
    i.size = "big"
```

You don't want to use neither `map` nor list comprehansion because they actually create new lists. And you don't need that overhead, do you?

Comment: I didn't know that map made a new list, that's raising some eyebrows.

Comment: @lukecampbell It has to. :) Consider this example: `x=[-1,1]` and `map(lambda i:i>0, x)`. Then look at `x` again. It didn't change at all. `Map` created new list. And it always does.

Comment: map creates new lists? i can't believe I havent been considering that.

Comment: It'd be nice to avoid introducing a new variable `i` here (or use `_`).

Comment: Love this answer. Sometimes the simplest answer is the best answer.

Answer (score 11):

While I agree that there is nothing wrong with

```
for i in my_things:
    i.size = "big"
```

some people are hot into python one-liners. ;)

One option is to add a set method to your class, which can then be called from lambda (essentially hiding the assignment in a function):

```
class Thing(object):
    def setSize(self, size):
        self.size = size

map(lambda i: i.setSize("big"), my_things)
```

Comment: This still creates a new list!!

Comment: That's true, but that was not a requirement. Given the by-reference nature of objects it will change the objects in the original list just as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `__setattr__` method to assign the attribute in a list comprehension.  Although, according to some SO threads, using list comprehensions without using the output is not pythonic.

```
[i.__setattr__('size', 'big') for i in my_things]
```

Comment: This still generates a new list to replace the old. Also will only work if `__setattr__()` returns `self` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> I think this is the problem with using map() or list comprehensions.

Not entirely.

```
my_things[:] = map(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe like this on python3:

```
[dict(**i.__dict__, size='big') for i in my_things]
```

or

```
map(lambda x: dict(**x.__dict__, size='big'), my_things)
```

if i is dict not object

```
[dict(**i, size='big') for i in my_things]
```

on python2

```
[dict(i.copy(), size='big') for i in my_things]  # isinstance(i, dict)
[dict(i.__dict__.copy(), size='big') for i in my_things]  # isinstance(i, object)
```