# Bulk MongoDB / Pymongo Insert with Datetime

Tags: python, mongodb

I have code that looks like the following, which executes every minute:

```
huge_list = query_results()  # Returns a long list of dictionaries.
db.objects.insert(huge_list)
```

I need the current datetime appended to *each* object in the list before insertion. Is there some way I can modify the insert command so it also appends a 'datetime' field, and if not what would be the most efficient way of doing this? There are several thousands records in the response dictionary, so I feel like visiting each index of the list and appending a field may not be the most efficient method.

Later I will need to be able to query for records individually from the whole group, and also for records within a specific datetime range.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like this MongoDB feature request is what you want: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17540

Comment: Definitely. But in the meantime while this is being implemented, what can I do?

Comment: Without server support you'll have to iterate your list and set the date, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554470/how-to-apply-function-to-elements-of-a-list.